# Algorithm for school scheduling

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinatorics

The task is this. Class 11a should teach 35 hours per week (6 days.without Sunday) In day they must teach 6 hours (maximum).Subjects:

"Matematika" -4 hours per week, "Fizika" -4 hours, "Rusi" - 2 hours, "Anglisi" -2 hours, "Naqsha" -2 hours,
"Biologiya" -2 hours, "Himiya" -2 hours, "Botanika" -2 hours, "Adabiyot" -3 hours,
"Zabon-3 hours", "Huquq" -3 hours, "TXT" -2 hours, "TDQ" - 4.

I created class like this :

```
 class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,int> Subjects { get; set; }
    public int MaxHoursInDay { get; set; }
    public int MaxHoursInWeek { get; set; }

}
```

Then  I filled  the data:

```
 Class _class = new Class();
        _class.Name = "11 a";
        _class.MaxHoursInDay = 5;
        _class.MaxHoursInWeek = 35;
        _class.Subjects = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        _class.Subjects.Add("Matematika", 4);
        _class.Subjects.Add("Fizika", 4);
        _class.Subjects.Add("Rusi", 2);
        ...
```

Now I wanna to generate all possible options for scheduling. Is there any formula or algorithm for solving the problem?

Comment: Strangely (coincidentally) enough, that's the bit the teacher wants you to figure out for your self

Comment: what are you mean? What kind of teacher?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No. It's part of my project

Comment: Your problem is a [constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), solve that. And maybe the Halting problem as well while you are at it.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that maybe the 4 hours of mathematics can be splitted to 2 2-hours courses? Or can't they be?

Comment: Yes. They can be 2 hours

Answer (score 0):

This is not the fastest and neither the cleanest way to do it but it is a a basic logic of the process.

- First put in a `List` all you classes with their hours.
- Then generate all the permutation of the list. This create all sorting possible for the sequence. This can create thousands or thousands of possibility. See [MoreLinq Permutation](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#permutations) as an example.
- Once you have all the permutation you need to create your days of class in order to see how much days this combinaison span over. So iterate each permutations.
- For each permutation create a list of class and call it 'ClassDay' and then add your class in the order given by the permutation to the list only if the total hours would be below your threshold (5 hours).
- If the class you are trying to add would make the total surpasses the 5 hours store the `ClassDay` in another `List` (very important to keep) an start a new `ClassDay` and keep adding again and again using same logic (max 5 hours) until you have put all classes in a `ClassDay` of 5 hours max.
- Finally check how many `ClassDay` got created by each permutation. You you have anything other than 6 `ClassDay` for a single permutation that combination is not good. Only those with exactly 6 `ClassDay` are a valid combination.

If class can be split into different hour segment like 2 hours can get 2 times 1 hours you need to split all you classes in the smallest segment possible. You would then need a final pass to merge all classes in a day that are in sequence so if 3 x 1 hours Matematika follow each other you regroup them into 1 of 3 hours.

Comment: I just want to know how to generate this. For example with 123 i can generate 123,132,213,231,321,312. Is there any formula to generate this ?

Comment: Yes, look at the link i provided to `MoreLinq` permutation. it does exactly that